# Check if JSON Object starts with 'https' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have urls like this:

```
data:
{
  "zip": 442,
  "code": "AG",
  "capital": "london",
  "currency": {
    "code": "XCD",
    "name": "East"
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/",
  "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/"
  }
```

I want to write an if statement that checks if the object starts with a 'https:' and then tell it what to do.

This is what I have, but it doesn't make my urls clickable or returns its data.

```
if (jsonObject.startsWith("http://")) {
    const text = document.createElement("a");
    k.textContent = jsonObject;
    k.setAttribute("href", jsonObject);
    j.appendChild(k);
```

Comment: An object can't start with a string, just object **properties**.

Comment: Side note: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. But a string containing the JSON for an object can't start with `https` because it would need to start with `{` (optionally preceded by whitespace).

Comment: I really hope this is a typo but you've used `startsWith("http://")` without the `s` in `https://`...

Comment: What is `jsonObject`? Shouldn't you be referencing the properties of your object?

Comment: You create an `<a>` element, `text`, but don't do anything with it. What are `k` and `j`?

Answer (score 1):

You're close I believe, you just aren't accessing the actual values inside of the object.

If you want to check the Object's properties values and if they start with http/https you can loop through the object and use the same check.

```
jsonObject.values.forEach((value) => {
  if(value.startsWith("https://") {
    const text = document.createElement("a");
    k.textContent = value;
    k.setAttribute("href", value);
    j.appendChild(k);
  }
});
```

Comment: What is `.values` supposed to be? We don't know much about what this object looks like, but from what's posted it looks like a plain object with some properties in it.

Comment: One thing to note with this solution, I believe it will create 2 links for you. If you want just one link you can replace `jsonObject.values.forEach` with `if(jsonObject.url.startsWith("https://")`

Comment: `.values` would turn the object into an array holding the values of each property. You could then loop over those values determining if they start with the requested string.

Comment: JavaScript objects do not have a `.values` property unless the application explicitly puts one there, and then the value of that property can be anything.

Comment: @Shiloh ```if(jsonObject.url.startsWith("https://")``` returns a ```TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith')```

Comment: To be clear, are you referring to `jsonObject` in your code as literally `jsonObject` or are you using `data`? If this is all in a file and you are importing (or requiring) the json file as some other name you will instead need to refer to the object as something along the lines of `myImportName.data.url`